# BigQuery FATAL Flags positioning error through Google Cloud SDK (shell) on Windows

Tags: google-bigquery

This code:

```
    bq mk --transfer_config --target_dataset=my_dataset --display_name='My Scheduled Query' --params='{"query":"SELECT 1","destination_table_name_template":"my_table","write_disposition":"WRITE_TRUNCATE"}' --data_source=scheduled_query --schedule='every 24 hours'
```

works fine over macOS, but doesn't work on Windows. I get this error:

FATAL Flags positioning error: Flag '--params='{query:SELECT 1,destination_table_name_template:my_table,write_disposition:WRITE_TRUNCATE}'' appears after final command line argument. Please reposition the flag.
Run 'bq help' to get help.

Any ideas why is this happening?

EDIT: I added a white space before --display_name as recommended by @Elliott Brossard. I made a mistake while pasting the line in this post. So, still have the same error result.

EDIT 2: In Cloud Shell it works Ok. It's a Windows SDK issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add a space before each flag. You're missing one here before `--display_name`:

```
--target_dataset=my_dataset--display_name='My Scheduled Query'
```

I think if you separate the flag with a space, the command will work.

Comment: I added a white space before --display_name as recommended by you. I made a mistake while pasting the line in the post. So, still I have the same error result.